# HTTP proxy to a specified interface (ppp0)

Tags: linux, vpn, proxy, http

I have a VPN which I want to route traffic for specific websites through. I know how to do it I just don't know which utilities to use and how to configure.

The proposed solution:

Firefox -> Foxyproxy (filtering on regex) -> HTTP proxy configured to send data to ppp0 -> VPN interface (ppp0).

I have Foxyproxy set up to use the HTTP proxy when it matches a pattern. The bit where I am stuck is getting a HTTP proxy that will send request out on a specific interface. I have tried 'tinyproxy' but it does not seem to take notice of the 'bind 192.168.100.170' which is the IP address of my ppp0 VPN interface.

Can someone suggest a HTTP proxy that will allow this on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Squid will allow you to do this with the [tcp_outgoing_address](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/) directive

Of course squid is not really small footprint and can be daunting to configure, but the default config should be more then adequate for most uses.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, however at the moment each time I start the VPN tunnel it has a different IP address.  Hence the desire to forward to an interface rather than an IP address.  Is it possible to get the VPN tunnel to always have the same IP?

Answer (score 1):

The squid recommendation is best, because what you need is a program that allows setting the outbound interface usage.

Absent that, if you have another HTTP/web proxy server available at the other end of the PPP connection, set up your proxy to forward all requests that that proxy-on-VPN server. That will cause all the connections to open across the PPP interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be suitable to you, but here's how I set up a http proxy for myself:

I'm assuming you use Linux on your desktop and also on remote server.

1. [Setup key-based (passwordless) authentication](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm) with the server. This way ssh should not ask for passowrd when you connect to the server.
2. Get [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) (it will ensure stable tunnel).
3. Setup a socks5 proxy:

   autossh -M [port used to monitor connection] -D [local port used for forwarding] -nN -l [username] [server]

Example:

autossh -M 55777 -D 3333 -nN -l minder my.secret.server.net

Now go to FoxyProxy settings and configure it to use **localhost:3333** as your proxy server. Voila! You can also use -D option to setup port-forwarding through the tunnel.

Works perfectly on my machine.